# How to pass a parameter which includes a single quote in it from Jenkins to PowerShell? Unterminated quoted string

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, jenkins

In one of the stages in a Jenkins pipeline, I need to pass the values from parameters to a script. Sometimes these values may contain a single quote sign which disrupts the run and doesn't come through to the script.

```
sh "pwsh -file script.ps1 '${params.NAME}' '${params.DESCRIPTION}' '${params.SOMETHING}'"
```

Ie when the script is called in the stage, the passed parameters may look like this:

```
'Name' 'Somebody's description' 'Something'
```

As you can see it messes with the arguments being passed on. It produces the error of an unterminated quoted string. I need to pass only 3 args to the script as the params suggest.

Any ways to solve this? Should I add another stage before calling the script that formats the values of the params in a way that is acceptable to pass to the PowerShell script? If so, how should I format it? Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: If you can assume that your parameter values never contain `"`, replace the embedded `'...'` quoting with embedded `"..."` quoting, i.e. ``\"...\"``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash`'s builtin `printf` has a `%q` format string that will insert quotes for you.  You might try something like:

```
sh -c "$(printf "%q " pwsh -file script.ps1 "${NAME}" "${DESCRIPTION}" "${SOMETHING}")"
```

but I'm not sure at which point the params gets expanded.  This sort of thing is inherently fragile, though, and you should find a better way.